# <p> tag displayed inline, below two floating divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs: 'Div 1' and 'Div 2'. 'Div 1' has to be on the left side, 'Div 2' on the right side, both of them in the same line, and nothing between them.

Below I have two p tags: 'p 1' and 'p2'. I need to style them inline, next to each other, but they have to stay below the divs.

I have no problem with style divs. I can use float: left for 'Div 1' and float: right for 'Div 2'. The problem is with p tags. I am trying to use clear: both property but it does not work in this case. My p tags are floating next to 'Div 1', instead to stay below divs. How can I style p tags to stay inline, below the divs?

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#first-div {
    float: left;
}

#second-div {
    float: right;
}

p {
    clear: both;
    width: 80px;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first-div">Div 1.</div>
    <div id="second-div">Div 2.</div>
    <p>p 1</p>
    <p>p 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `clear` only applies to block-level elements, so with `display: inline` you are effectively preventing clear from working here.

Comment: Now it makes sense for me. The problem is that I need to have this p tags inline and I need to style them using the only p element.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the divs. Then use a `pseudoelement` with the `clear` property.

*As per @Scoots comment, there may be an advantage to using `display: table` instead of `display: block`* *as clearfix*.

```css
.wrapper>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

#first-div {
  float: left;
}

#second-div {
  float: right;
}

p {
  width: 80px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="first-div">Div 1.</div>
  <div id="second-div">Div 2.</div>
</div>
<p>p 1</p>
<p>p 2</p>
```

*update as per comment*

You could use a `:before` pseudoelement on the `<p>` immediately following the second div. This has the disadvantage of breaking up the border however.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


#first-div {
  float: left;
}

#second-div {
  float: right;
}

#second-div + p::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

p {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">Div 1.</div>
<div id="second-div">Div 2.</div>
<p>p 1</p>
<p>p 2</p>
```

Comment: Clearfix is often suggested to be `display: table` instead of block

Comment: @Scoots Thanks, why is that?

Comment: `display: table` is used to prevent collapsing margins between two stacked, clear-fixed containers.

Comment: @Scoots Thanks, do you have a link for me to read up on it? I found this interesting property I've never heard of --> `display: flow-root` https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/RKgevX

Comment: Here is where I read about it: https://www.fuseinteractive.ca/blog/understanding-humble-clearfix#.V6H_p2Wof6s. The relevant section is near the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! This works kind of, but I'm wondering why 'clear' property does not work in this case? Is it possible to do this cleaner way without an extra HTML?

Comment: @wlodekD Updated the answer. If you're not using borders on the `p` tag you may be able to use the second answer

Comment: Regarding `display:table` vs. `display:block` for "clearfixing" pseudo-element: here is a quick demo what can happen with the former (due to margin collapsing) if the container has both floating and non-floating children: http://jsfiddle.net/o9rbryxp/16/. So `display:table` version, that always prevents margin collapsing, is more reliable.

Comment: Thank you, sol and @Scoots. The problem seems to be easy to solve but it is not, and I can not find a satisfactory way. I will leave question unsolved for now.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#first-div,  div#second-div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#first-div {
    float: left;
}

#second-div {
    float: right;
}

p {
    width: 80px;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    display: inline;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">Div 1.</div>
<div id="second-div">Div 2.</div>

<div class="clearBoth">
  <p>p 1</p>
  <p>p 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is not bad but in this case, I have three divs now, and I need to have only two. I was trying doing the same and I used empty <h1> tag with clear: both property. Thank you!